# Horizontal aligning with CSS

Tags: css, alignment, css-float

this is my first post here on StackOverflow and I'm quite excited about it since Google has brought me here quite often in the search of comprehensive answers.

Anyways, my question is quite simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to align three small icons on the same line but to the right of my page/post title. The post heading code looks like this:

```
<div class="post-heading">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

The 3 icons need to have their own ID in order to function properly. They are inserted like this:

```
`#icon_container {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: normal;
font-size: medium;
width: 50px;}

`#icon_container #icon_1 {
    float: right;
    background-image: url(icon.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;}`


`#icon_container #icon_1 A {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    display: block;}`
```

So all I am trying to achieve here is to have the h1 title to the left, and on the same alignmnet to the right the 3 icons inserted with the above CSS. Can anyone help me out? I'd appreciate it a lot :)

Thanks all

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention the HTML code for the icons; here it is:

`<div id="icon_container"><div id="icon_1"><a href="#" id="icon_1_button"></a></div><div id="icon_2....</div><div style="clear:both"></div></div>`

Comment: could you please your `html` code of icon....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to float post-heading and the icon elements to the left.

```
<div class="post-heading" > < h1 >Title < /h1 > < /div>
<div id='icon_container'>
    <div id='icon_1'></div>
    <div id='icon_2'></div>
</div>

#icon_container, #icon_1, #icon_2, .post_heading {float:left;}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it worked! However now my content text is weirdly positioned..

Comment: Works perfect! Let me see if I run into further problems. But until now, thank you for the support :)

Comment: my pleasure Kaneda, if my answer helped solve your problem be sure to click on the checkmark to select it as the answer.   good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The h1 and the images needs to have the

```
style="display:inline"
```

if you want the images to have the same horizontal alignment.

Comment: i believe this would only be true if the `#icon` elements were in the same div as the `h1`

Answer (score 0):

Try floating your `#post-heading h1` to the left:

```
#post-heading h1 {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

Fist one is

```
<div class="post-heading">
  <h1>Title</h1>
<span class="icon_container"> [icon] </span>
</div>
.post-heading *{
    display:inline;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/nsZpc/)

2nd is

`.post_heading h1{float:left;}`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/maxisam/nsZpc/1/)